# Making a Calendar with Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

https://thielcole.github.io/ionic2/2017/02/03/Ionic2-Calendar.html
I followed this link and tried exactly what he said but ran into a lot of errors.
I want to make calendar with different color events. I tried https://devdactic.com/ionic-calendar-app/ this and works well but what I want is dot events on calendar with event in different color as first link

Answer (score 1):

Can you change

> in calendar.ts

```
 .no-events-label {
      ..
      color: darkgrey; // change what you want
    }

 .calendar-event-inner {
      ..
      background-color: #3a87ad; // change what you want
      color: white; // change what you want

    }
```